# Append new divs in order of time[jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
$("body").delegate(".u-post-button", "click", function(){ 
      var btn = $(this);
      var currentPost = btn.parents('.content-event');
      var content = btn.siblings('textarea[name="comment-post-content"]').val();
      if (content)
      {
      var event_id = currentPost.find('.event-id').val();
      var url= '/post-comments/'+event_id +'/';
                content: content
               }
      $.post(url , data, function(data){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        var lang = '';
        $.each(obj, function() {
          lang += this['html'];
        });
        $(currentPost.find('.latest-comment')).append(lang); 
        $(currentPost.find('.comment-post-content')).val("");  
      });
      } 
      else
      {
        $(currentPost.find('.comment-post-content')).attr("rows", "1");
      } 
      return false;
    });
```

This is the script to post a comment and then putting the returned json after the".latest-comment" div. It works fine, but comments order is from oldest to latest as we go down. I wan the reverse. How can I do that? I tried using prependTo in place of append but, then the comments won't show. This is the html,

```
<div class="content-event">
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <textarea class="comment-post-content" name="comment-post-content" cols="55" rows="1" placeholder="Add a comment..."></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" class="event-id" value="{{ event.id }}">
        <input type="submit" class="u-post-button" value="Post comment" />
      </form>

    </div>
<div class="latest-comment"></div>
```

Comment: post your html too and if possible create a jsfiddle...would be helpful to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned that you've tried `prependTo()`, but have you tried `prepend()`? They work differently, which is why your comments probably disappeared.

**jQuery Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/prepend/